# numpysavetxt column header

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, numpy

I'm using np.savetxt to create a csv file, but I'm not sure if I can add custom headers to each column. For example, I want my csv to look like:
[sample excel format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6SZz.png)

For the column headers, preferably I would want it to increment by 1, and possibly index ahead while skipping some ints (I'll have other variables that increment/skip when forming my np array, so I could save the variables in a separate array if that works).

As for the row headers, I'll be reading in various files in my directory, so it'd be most optimal to print the file names there (TypeA, TypeB, etc), otherwise anything that increments works as well. Does savetxt support this, or would something else be more optimal?

If it helps...I'll have at least 100 columns and 200 rows, so manually listing all of them wouldn't work too well.

Comment: The `header` parameter makes it easy to include a header line - just a string of  your choosing.  Play with the `comments` parameter if you don't want '#'.  Row header is harder, requiring a structured array, and attendant `fmt` complications.

Comment: @hpaulj I've tried the header parameter..but other than manually listing all of headers (over 100...) I'm not sure if I could use some sort of loop or something.. Not sure if I could set header = temp, where temp is an array of values, but that didn't seem to work for me unless my format was off.

Comment: The `savetxt` author expects you to use standard Python methods to format the string.  For comma delimiter, `', '.join(['one','two','three'])` should be enough. With with some spacing, `','.join(['%10s']*3)%('one','two','three')`.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote helpful answers and mark an answer as accepted if you find it sufficient to solve your problem! See the help section on [someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're dependent on using comments in the file you could do the following:

```
import numpy as np
import string
someData=np.random.random(size=(5,4))
# Edit: OP asked for numeric headers in the comments,
# so here they are
columnNames=["Type%d" % (i+1) for i in range(someData.shape[1])]

# For the previous answer, uncomment both below
# letters=string.ascii_uppercase
# columnNames=["Type%s" % letter for letter in letters]


# Index header
columnNames.insert(0,"Index")
rowIndices=np.arange(someData.shape[0]).reshape((-1,1))
# Make sure the first row are integers and the rest floats
format="%i"
format=format+",%.8f"*someData.shape[1]
# Remember to remove the comment character!
np.savetxt("mydata.csv", np.concatenate([rowIndices,someData], axis=1),fmt=format,comments='',header=','.join(columnNames))
```

With a `5x4` dimention on `someData`, this is the `mydata.csv` CSV output:

```
Index,Type1,Type2,Type3,Type4
0,0.90379913,0.75924195,0.94299403,0.81502046
1,0.62159008,0.41111464,0.89520339,0.17943100
2,0.65283441,0.40989492,0.61787211,0.93547408
3,0.24923627,0.54666970,0.41175465,0.53969919
4,0.21083701,0.19248967,0.23727747,0.73555606
```

Comment: This helps quite a bit, thanks! Instead of string.ascii_uppercase, do you know of a way to get 'Type1...Type11, Type12, etc' ? I couldn't find any string operations that went past single digits.

Comment: Hopefully last question..for the index column, how would you make the rows also say Type1...etc instead of 0, 1.. etc?

Comment: @ChrisTang this can't be done, because Numpy won't know how to treat the text on loading!